# Locking a collection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, locking

I have got a session bean method that uses Hibernate to add child to a indexed collection of an entity. However, since there may be multiple threads accessing the method at the same time, in some weird cases it happened that a duplicate index will be assigned to different children (bug in Hibernate? I don't know).

To prevent it, I would like to try to lock the whole entity as well as it's collection so other threads would not be able to modify it while another thread is updating it. I know we can set lock mode to an entity, but how about a collection? Can it lock any other transactions from adding a new child?

Please enlighten me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to use synchronized collection wrappers. You can use the static methods in Collections class ([Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)). For example:

```
List<String> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new List<String>());
```

As for locking at entity level, a synchronized code block locked on the entity should do the trick.

```
 synchronized (entityInstance) 
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: I am afraid it would block all collections of that type, which is not necessarily belongs to the same entity. I only want to lock the collection  which belongs to the same entity.

Comment: No, it would not. Collections' static methods return an instance of a synchronized collection. Those collections are synchronized at instance level, NOT class level.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But it brings to the question about if Hibernate shares the same referenced entity object between different threads in a EJB...

Comment: I have no experience with EJB, but hibernate returns the same instance while in the same session. If all your threads work with the same session object then the instance of entity should be shared.

Comment: Then I am afraid not. The EJB methods opens new session every time. And from the hibernate doc they encourage us to leave the concurrency control to hibernate and DB, so I may try to read about the locking strategy...